# Keeping configuration information in Django for frequent use

Tags: django

I read a JSON file for configuration information that the Django app needs.  Rather than read it every time, I'd like to keep it in memory somewhere.  Only, I don't know how to do this in Django.  What's the best way to keep simple configuration information in RAM, so that it's accessible anywhere in the app?

Comment: Why does it need to be in memory? Surely this is something that only needs to be done once

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the variables that you want to access as Environment variables and access them in your code.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "<your_key>" # set environment variable
os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY') # access environment variable in your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to version control what ever config it is and use it to run the system the reason being it will be extremely difficult to replicate or debug these kind of issues.

But if you feel your scenario is exceptional your best go will be [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/6323666).

> You can use a global variable in other functions by declaring it as global in each function that assigns to it